# Grilles inside a double pane 7 foot palladium window rattling when closing door

Tags: windows

What is the best way to stop the grilles inside a double pane 7 foot palladium window from rattling when closing the door?

Comment: Is the window in the wall or in the door? In either case, close the door more gently?

Comment: In the wall below the door. Rattles even when the door id closed gently.

Comment: The door is on the 2nd floor and the windows are on the 1st (or other, similar different floor scenario)?

Answer (score 0):

If the grills are between the panes of glass then there is a problem since those grill should be held fast at the time of MFG. I would contact the door MFG and inquire about that problem. There may even be a warranty for that problem. Do you know who made the door in question?